# TFS 2010 cannot add solution

Tags: tfs

We are trying to add a VB.NET 2010 solution to a Team Foundation Server 2010. When we right-click the solution and select "Add Solution to Source Controll..." it pops-up a message "The file 'sample.vb' cannot be added to the source countrol because the item has no source control mapping. If you choose one of the Ignore options the operation will continue without addint the file."

We wonder what the reason for this is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We found that the file in question was a linked one and not part of the project itself. The rest of the files went in the TFS without any issues. So, you were right that the file was outside of the main project folder.

Answer (score 1):

You need to make sure that the file is created in a directory that is mapped to the current TFS workspace.